# I am getting an error 1055 trying to group after a join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I am new to SQL and I am having trouble with finding out how to group after a join. The goal is to find out what country raised the most.

```
SELECT x.country_id
     , x.pledged
     , y.id
     , y.name 
  FROM campaign x
  LEFT 
  JOIN country y
    ON x.country_id = y.id
```

This brings up the columns required and it's all fine

When I add:

```
GROUP BY country.name
```

or

```
GROUP BY campaign.country_id
```

I get an error that I don't understand.

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'kickstarter.campaign.country_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic rule for "group by" is that the column that has been selected has to either be applied with aggregated function or it has shown up after the group by. Try the below one, where we are trying to sum up all the pledged money for each country.

```
SELECT country.name, sum(campaign.pledged) country_pledged
FROM campaign LEFT JOIN country ON campaign.country_id = country.id
GROUP BY country.name ORDER BY campaign.pledged DESC
```

Comment: Isaac sorry to be a hassle but i have one more question I'm stuck on, I need to see the top performing categories. can you spot anything wrong with this query, I have tried a lot of varients. I used your above answer and got this. SELECT country.name, sum(campaign.pledged) country_pledged
FROM campaign LEFT JOIN country ON campaign.country_id = country.id
GROUP BY country.name

Answer (score 0):

You need to either group by all columns (like `GROUP BY campaign.country_id, campaign.pledged, country.id, country.name`) or use aggregate functions in SELECT list.

Comment: Hmm, this does not make the country name or id columns stack so that i can see who raised the most money it just leaves the table the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Below SQL should work. Please note your GROUP BY and SELECT clause should be in sync for aggregation to work.

```
SELECT country.name, count(1) ccount 
FROM campaign LEFT JOIN country ON campaign.country_id = country.id
GROUP BY country.name ORDER BY 2 DESC
```